# Python reading files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .csv with 3000 rows of data in 2 columns like this:

```
uc007ayl.1  ENSMUSG00000041439
uc009mkn.1  ENSMUSG00000031708
uc009mkn.1  ENSMUSG00000035491
```

In another folder I have a graphs with name like this:

```
uc007csg.1_nt_counts.txt
uc007gjg.1_nt_counts.txt
```

You should notice those graphs have a name in the same format of my 1st column

I am trying to use python to identify those rows that have a graph and print the name of 2nd column in a new .txt file

These are the codes I have

```
import csv
with open("C:/*my dir*/UCSC to Ensembl.csv", "r") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

But this as far as I can get and I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
import csv
import os.path
with open("C:/*my dir*/UCSC to Ensembl.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        graph_filename = os.path.join("C:/folder", row[0] + "_nt_counts.txt")
        if os.path.exists(graph_filename):
            print (row[1])
```

Note that the repeated calls to [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) may slow down the process, especially if the directory lies on a remote filesystem and does not significantly more files than the number of lines in the CSV file. You may want to use [`os.listdir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738276/4279) instead:

```
import csv
import os

graphs = set(os.listdir("C:/graph folder"))
with open("C:/*my dir*/UCSC to Ensembl.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] + "_nt_counts.txt" in graphs:
            print (row[1])
```

Comment: I tried your code but I get this error saying 'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback@phihag

Comment: I think I found the error, I forgot to put .png after .txt because those files are graphs

Comment: file should be opened in 'rb' mode on Python 2.x. You don't need to check every file, a single [os.listdir()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738276/4279) is enough

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're right about `"rb"`, fixed. `os.listdir` is only faster if the number of entries in the CSV file is not significantly smaller than the number of files in the target directory. Added the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to see if `print row[0]` really gives the correct file identifier.

Second, concatenate the path to the files with `row[0]` and check if this full path exists (if the file exists, actually) with `os.path.exists(path)` (see http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists ).

If it exits, you can write the row[1] (the second column) to a new file with `f2.write("%s\n" % row[1]` (first you have to open `f2` for writing of course).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the next step would be to check if the file exists? There are a few ways, but I like the  [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach.

```
try:
   with open(os.path.join(the_dir,row[0])) as f: pass
except IOError:
   print 'Oops no file'
```

`the_dir` is the directory where the files are.

Comment: In this case, EAFP is not a good idea. There is a fundamental difference between a file being there and actually opening the file. Opening the file will usually trigger it actually being preread, requires file handle management (and locking on Windows), and requires the file to be readable by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = open('result.txt', 'w')
for line in open('C:/*my dir*/UCSC to Ensembl.csv', 'r'):
    line = line.split(',')
    try:
        open('/path/to/dir/' + line[0] + '_nt_counts.txt', 'r')
    except:
        continue
    else:
        result.write(line[1] + '\n')
result.close()
```

Comment: This implementation can leak file handles on some Python implementations, and requires the current user to be able to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import os

# get prefixes of all graphs in another directory
suff = '_nt_counts.txt'
graphs = set(fn[:-len(suff)] for fn in os.listdir('another dir') if fn.endswith(suff))

with open(r'c:\path to\file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    # extract 2nd column if the 1st one is a known graph prefix
    names = (row[1] for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t') if row[0] in graphs)
    # write one name per line
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for name in names:
            print >>output_file, name
```